Using SQL or Spark-SQL - How To Update Column Value Based on Aggregation Record Count Greater Than 1
I have a dataset that involves customers opting out of a promotion. They will always have a unique customer_id but can share a living space. The issue comes when two customers living in the same household have different methods of promotion actions (add, delete, NULL) on the same day.
The issue comes when multiple household members have separate promo_action values occur on the same promo_action_date. If one household member chooses delete we need to ensure all household members are treated as a deletion for the promotion. If this is the case, how can you update the promo_action column if there are multiple records sharing the same household_id and promo_action_date, but different values for the promo_action? The requirement would be to update the promo_action_date to "DELETE" if this were the case.
The promo_action_household table has the 4 columns seen in the headers here.
Before



customer_id
household_id
promo_action
promo_action_date




101
54
DELETE
2024-10-03


157
54
NULL
2024-10-03



After



customer_id
household_id
promo_action
promo_action_date




101
54
DELETE
2024-10-03


157
54
DELETE
2024-10-03



I was hoping to update the columns of the records to "DELETE" if this condition was met querying the promo_action_household table. SQL or spark-sql are the goal tools to use here.
select household_id, promo_action_date, count(*) from promo_action_household group by household_id, promo_action_date having count(*)>1


Please include example records for household 54 that have promo_action_date other than 2024-10-03 and have promo_action NULL. This will clarify the problem.

Why do you care if the household has more than one member? The WHERE criteria already requires at least 2 records within the same Household+date group ( one with promo_action = 'DELETE' and at least 1 other with promo_action =NULL. Are you dealing with a large set of records where a 2 stage filter process might improve efficiency?

It's for a process that populates a table with a distinct primary key constraint for the households but requires a left join to this table to acquire promo_action values for the unique household. A 2 stage filter process would help and will probably be something I suggest moving forward.

The solution might be something like this:
--Update the promo_action_household table to set all members of a household with promo_action='DELETE' if any member of the household already has promo_action='DELETE' and has the same promo_action_date
UPDATE a SET a.promo_action='DELETE' 
FROM promo_action_household a
WHERE  EXISTS
(--Matching household_id/promo_action_date groups with promo_action='DELETE'
 SELECT *
 FROM promo_action_household b  
 WHERE b.promo_action='DELETE'
   AND a.household_id = b.household_id 
   AND a.promo_action_date  = b.promo_action_date 
)
AND promo_action!='DELETE'  --no need to update records that already have DELETE


This was close! I needed do group by having for count(distinct promo_action) > 1 and count(distinc promo_action_date) = 1. I will mark this as complete but thank you for your help.
